# Julia error: ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: in Vararg, in count, expected Int64, got Type{Float64}

Tags: arrays, error-handling, compiler-errors, julia

I declare some vectors in a mutable struct. I then create and use them in other methods, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: in Vararg, in count, expected Int64, got Type{Float64}
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at C:\Users\taylo\OneDrive\SummerResearch2021\RK Programs\Julia\RK_JuliaOriginal2.jl:4
 [2] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:380
 [3] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:368
 [4] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:296
 [5] _start() at .\client.jl:506
in expression starting at C:\Users\taylo\OneDrive\SummerResearch2021\RK Programs\Julia\RK_JuliaOriginal2.jl:4
```

I did see some other stuff that was along these lines, but the solutions either couldn't directly be applied to this or didn't help. I am still very new to Julia.
Below is all of the relevant code (It is missing a lot of variable declarations and calculations, but that stuff was irrelevant for this. Thank you!

```
mutable struct JuliaNeuron
    RK_dm::NTuple{Float64}
    RK_dh::NTuple{Float64}
    RK_dn::NTuple{Float64}
    RK_dVm::NTuple{Float64}
end

function RK(neuron::JuliaNeuron, RKindex::Int64, RK_dm, RK_dh, RK_dn, RK_dVm)
    RK_dm[RKindex] = aM * (1 - m) - bM * m
    RK_dh[RKindex] = aH * (1 - h) - bH * h
    RK_dn[RKindex] = aN * (1 - n) - bN * n
end

function calculateNextTimeStep(stimulus::Float64, neuron::JuliaNeuron, RK_dm, RK_dh, RK_dn, RK_dVm)
    # k1 Runge-Kutta step
    RK(neuron, 0, stimulus, neuron.m, neuron.h, neuron.n, neuron.v, RK_dm, RK_dh, RK_dn, RK_dVm)
end

function simulate()

    RK_dm = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    RK_dh = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    RK_dn = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
    RK_dVm = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

    # create a neuron
    neuron = JuliaNeuron(RK_dm, RK_dh, RK_dn, RK_dVm)

    for i = 1:N
        push!(t, (i*dt))
        push!(Vm, calculateNextTimeStep(stimAmplitude, neuron, RK_dm, RK_dh, RK_dn, RK_dVm))
    end
end
```

Comment: for your first problem, you could define the struct as `mutable struct JuliaNeuron{T<:Real}` and  replace every `Float64` by T. The other thing that's not runnable here is that the fields `m`, `h`, `n`, `v` are not defined. You want to replace them by `RK_dm`, etc. (or vice versa). Fix that and edit your question if it's still not working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `NTuple` type requires the number of elements hence most likely you wanted to write:

```
mutable struct JuliaNeuron2{N}
    RK_dm::NTuple{N,Float64}
    RK_dh::NTuple{N,Float64}
    RK_dn::NTuple{N,Float64}
    RK_dVm::NTuple{N,Float64}
end
```

This data structure now can be used in the following way:

```
julia> JuliaNeuron2{2}((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8))
JuliaNeuron2{2}((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0), (7.0, 8.0))
```